# Recycler View scroll position is initially not on top

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, adapter

So, I've got this structure in my app:

```
RecyclerView
     |
      --> View
      --> CustomListView
      --> CustomListView
```

After all views are loaded in the adapters (RecyclerViewAdapter and the ListViewAdapters) my scroll position is about on the middle of the page - but my desired and initial scroll position should be on top.

So, I know I can change the scroll position through the recycler view, but the problem is: when should I do it? I don't have any callback from the adapters, so I don't know when all the views are loaded..

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure, may be in `onStart()` method.

Comment: nop, did not work, probably because of this nested structure

Comment: why do you have this structure?  you do not need to nest a listview or customlistview inside a recyclerview.  you should be able to create what you need using only a recyclerview.